# Nesting Navigators with React Navigators - 'Home' should declare a screen

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I am currently working with React Native and the new React Navigation. There I'm trying to follow the [tutorial for nesting navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting), but there is always an error:

```
Route 'Home' should declare a screen. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Home: {
   screen: MyScreen,
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I start the navigators individually, they work. But unfortunately not combined.

This is the App.js, which I have created using the tutorial:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text,
    View,
    Button
} from 'react-native';

import {
    StackNavigator,
    TabNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome',
    };
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return <View>
            <Text>Hello!</Text>
            <Button
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat', { user: 'Daniel' })}
                title="ReactNavigation Test"
            />
        </View>;
    }
}

class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'ReactNavigation Test',
    };
    render() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Neue Seite für den Navigator. Hallo {params.user}!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class RecentChatsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Text>List of recent chats</Text>
    }
}

class AllContactsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Text>List of all contacts</Text>
    }
}

const ReactNativeTest = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
    Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});

const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Recent: { screen: RecentChatsScreen },
    All: { screen: AllContactsScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeTest', () => ReactNativeTest);
```

Maybe you can help me there. I asked the same question [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/571), but maybe this is the better place for the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made this mistake when I was starting out as well...

Put `MainScreenNavigator` above `ReactNativeTest`.

As you currently have it, MainScreenNavigator doesn't exist when it's called.

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Recent: { screen: RecentChatsScreen },
    All: { screen: AllContactsScreen },
});

const ReactNativeTest = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
    Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I made the same mistake too!

Comment: Whoops! no hoisting! I was thinking that since it's JS, it's gonna resolve the variable no matter where I define it.

Comment: What happened to Javascript hoisting here...?